# TypeScript Interface dynamic value type

Tags: typescript, dynamic, interface

It's possible to declare a interface like this;

```
interface TableColumn<T> {
fieldName: key of T
render: (value: **value type of the fieldName** ) => void

}
```

I want to make a type related to `keyof T`.
**this is what I want to do:**

```
type Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface TableColumn<T> {
  fieldName: keyof T;
  render: (value: /* type of keyof T */) => unknown;
}

//eaxample: 

const NameColumn: TableColumn<Person> = {
  fieldName: 'name', // keyof T is Person[name]
  render: (value: ??) // ==> value must be a string type, becasuse Person.name is a string type
}


const AgeColumn: TableColumn<Person> = {
  fieldName: 'age', // keyof T is Person[age]
  render: (value: ??) // ==> value must be number type, becasuse Person.age is a number type
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2BnAsgQzFAXigG8AoKKAMwEsIEATARgC4oNgAnatAcwG5yVWgwBMrNKgBGEDgIC+A0t2AzKOAMbQAKjkkII8ZOgA8WqBAAeKtPQxQA1hBBxKsRKky4wAPhKCadPQAcjgoEKxaAhQcEDYyrAAUAG44yOFuRp54ANpaALoAlIS+SGj2aHAA7mjypEA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi @wonderflame, thank you for answer. But your approach isn't what I want do.

Comment: what about [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2BnAsgQzFAXigG8AoKKAMwEsIEATARgC4oNgAnatAcwG5yVWgwBMrNKgBGEDgIC+A0qEhQAKjkkII8ZOgA8qgDRQA0lAgAPYBDT0MUANYQQcSmsKPnrtQD4PZy2tbezMAfhJBGjp6ADkcFAhWEwEKDht6GVYACgA3HGREtQBtEwBdAEpCPyQ0BzQ4AHc0eShxCByZUi6AYzhMYCgcVnVNbURUND0dCew8PyIyCiiGOITWAHJlpnXDQTTbTKhc-KQISoI-dfXSOSA)?

Comment: thank you so much. That's exactly what i wanted :)

Comment: okay, will write the answer soon

Comment: So `K extends K ?` splits the union. Good to know.

Comment: @Dimava any condition that will be always true does that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we just use the following code:

```
type TableColumn<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
  fieldName: K;
  render: (value: T[K]) => unknown;
};
```

The result won't be the expected one unfortunately, because the `value` in the `render` function will have the type of a union of all possible types in `T`. This can be fixed by using the [conditional type distribution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). When a distribution is applied to a union the code after the condition is applied to each member of the union separately:

```
type FirstToArray<T> = T[]
type First = FirstToArray<string | number> // (string | number)[]

type SecondToArray<T> = T extends any ? T[] : never
type Second = SecondToArray<string | number> // string[] | number[]
```

Let's apply this logic to our type:

```
type TableColumn<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = K extends K ? {
  fieldName: K;
  render: (value: T[K]) => unknown;
} : never
```

Testing:

```
type ColumnsMap = {
  field1: string;
  field2: number;
};

const a: TableColumn<ColumnsMap> = {
  fieldName: 'field1',
  render: (value) => '' // value: string
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2BnAsgQzFAXigG8AoKKAMwEsIEATARgC4oNgAnatAcwG5yVWgwBMrNKgBGEDgIC+A0qEhQAKjkkII8ZOgA8qgDRQA0lAgAPYBDT0MUANYQQcSmsKPnrtQD4PZy2tbezMAfhJBGjp6ADkcFAhWEwEKDht6GVYACgA3HGREtQBtEwBdAEpCPyQ0BzQ4AHc0eShxCByZUi6AYzhMYCgcVnVNbURUND0dCew8PyIyCiiGOITWAHJlpnXDQTTbTKhc-KQISoI-dfWoAHobqDyC1nYuXlI5IA)